# spacing between trees in the `forest` package

Tags: forest

I'm trying to use the `forest` package to draw adjacent trees. My problem is that the trees are too close to each other.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document} 
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north}
[$a+b\cdot c$
    [$\oplus$
        [$b\cdot c$
        ]
        [$a$
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north}
[$a+b\cdot c$
    [$\oplus$
        [$\otimes$
            [$c$]
            [$b$]
        ]
        [$a$
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand the following code doesn't generate two adjacent trees, but only the node `a`.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
for tree={grow=north}
[a
]
[b
]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

How can I draw adjacent trees?

Comment: try to insert `\hfil` or `\hfill` between `forest` trees: `\end{forest}\hfil\begin{forest}`

Comment: @Zarko works like a charm!

Comment: then we can consider question solved by comment?

Comment: @Zarko I would like to wait a few hours - perhaps someone will show me how to create such diagrams with `forest`. Is that okay?

Comment: OK, i will not take any action. About `forest` diagram, this is not clear what you expect. To have all trees on one image?

Comment: @Zarko Yep. [spaces]

Comment: Please post complete code we can compile. You cannot draw 2 trees in one `forest` environment. You can fake it, if you want, but a `forest` consists of a single tree. It is very misleadingly named.

Comment: @Zarko how can I write an "equation" of trees? The `hfil` command is great, but if I replace it with `=` the spacing is bad.

Comment: @Arrow, it seems that I not understand your question(s). So, better is address your above comment to *cfr*, which answer you already accept and where she also provide the placing of equations. If you have new problem, than is better to ask for help with new question. It will be more visible to audience as your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only one tree is permitted in any `forest`, whose name is hopelessly misleading. You can have many trees with Forest, but only one in each `forest`. That is, a forest of trees requires many `forest`s.

If you really want multiple trees in a `forest`, you can wrap them in a tree shell with a phantom root.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{forest}
\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  for tree={grow=north}
  [, phantom, fit=band
    [$a+b\cdot c$
      [$\oplus$
          [$b\cdot c$
          ]
          [$a$
          ]
      ]
    ]
    [$a+b\cdot c$
      [$\oplus$
          [$\otimes$
              [$c$]
              [$b$]
          ]
          [$a$
          ]
      ]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: fake tree for <code>forest</code> with two trees i.e. too many]

I don't know why you would bother, though.